# Interface inheritance and derived classes

Tags: c#

Why can't I do something like this in c# (pseudo code follows)

```
Interface1
{
    Method1();   
}

Interface2 : Interface1
{
    Method2();
}

Class1 : Interface1
{
    Method1()
    {
    }
}

Class2 : Class1, Interface2
{
    Method2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, or error that you're trying to fix?

Comment: Probably because barely half of that code is valid C# syntax. Do you have actual C# code that doesn't compile?

Comment: Just use `interface` before the interface name and return-type before method name

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield the code is just pseudo code. My problem was a spelling mistake which matched another interface and I didn't check the error message correctly. Unfortunately my connection went down before I could correct the post. Anyway a "Yes you can" would have sufficed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, if you correct your mistake in defining an interface and specify a return type on your methods.

```
interface Interface1
{
    void Method1();   
}

interface Interface2 : Interface1
{
    void Method2();
}

class Class1 : Interface1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1, Interface2
{
    public void Method2()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it.

```
public interface Interface1
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface Interface2 : Interface1
{
    void Method2();
}

public class Class1 : Interface1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2 : Class1, Interface2
{
    public void Method2()
    {
    }
}
```