# Why WCF classes require interface inheritance but plain classes not?

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance

This code works in plain classes:

```
public interface IServiceBase
{
    void BaseMethod();
}

public class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    public void BaseMethod() { }
}

public interface ITestService // : IServiceBase - it doesn't reqiure
                              // in plain classes but in WCF it does.
{
    void TestMethod();
}

public class TestService : ServiceBase, ITestService
{
    public void TestMethod() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ts = new TestService();
        ts.BaseMethod();
    }
}
```

But in WCF context the client can't see the BaseMethod until you inherite ITestService from IServiceBase:

```
public interface ITestService : IServiceBase
```

Why?

I thought

```
TestService : ServiceBase
```

already includes

```
TestService : IServiceBase
```

In plain classes it is, but in WCF it is not.

My question isn't this question [Interface inheritance and derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823453/interface-inheritance-and-derived-classes)

Comment: How do you create your proxy class? By code generation or manually sharing the same interfaces between client and server by using ServiceChannel?

Comment: Through AddServiceReference option in Visual Studio.

Comment: Then @TomTom answer is correct.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I see, but want to have a reference that WCF designers decide to confide to interfaces and not to implementations even though they have access to both on the server side. And why they choose interfaces and not implementation to form the data packet to send to client proxy.

Comment: You have those two solutions: creating a proxy by using code generation or using ServiceChannel. The latter let you share code between server and client. Code Generation (Add service Reference) must be use if you not access to the server code. Code generation is done by looking in the WSDL file not the code on the server. It don't care.

Comment: @CodeNotFound But if I'll use code sharing the clients can see the server's implementation in runtime or it works only when I write client's code but after compiling and running the client can't see it? In other words if I don't want the client see my server code I can use only code generation through AddServiceReference i.e. interfaces?

Comment: You put the interface in a separate asembly (project) then share the assembly between the client and server. The implementation of the interface remain onlyto the server side and inly on that side.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Now I see. Your explanation is more complete and full than TomTom's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WCF is based on implementing proxies automatically (on the client side) and determining a contract (interface) that a service exposes - while the implementation may and normally is in a different project. Basic design principle of using the correct tool (interface) for the job (describing an interface).

Comment: So it seems that if client proxies can somehow see the implementation (TestService) they can find that IServiceBase is already implemented in TestService through inheritance from ServiceBase, right? But by design .NET creators decide not to perform it in WCF services but perform it in plain classes? Right?

Comment: They do not see the implementation. THe pack up the request in a data packet.